Show integral of element-wise square of matrix exponential + I is invertible
Question:
Let $\mathbf{Q}$ be a matrix whose eigenvalues have positive real parts, and let $\mathbf{B}$ be the matrix with entries
\begin{equation}
B_{ij} = \int_0^\infty ((e^{-Qt})_{ij})^2 dt.
\end{equation}
I want to show that $\mathbf{I + B}$ is invertible.
My attempt:
Let $\mathbf{b}_j$ denote the $j$'th column of $\mathbf{B}$. Then $\mathbf{b}_j = \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{Z}_j)$, where $\mathbf{Z}_j$ is the solution to the continuous Lyapunov equation
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{QZ}_j + \mathbf{Z}_j \mathbf{Q}^T = \mathbf{E}_{jj}
\end{equation}
(Here, $\mathbf{E}_{jj}$ is the matrix with value $1$ in entry $(j, j)$ and $0$ otherwise.)
Now suppose $\mathbf{x}$ satisfies $(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{B})\,\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$. I want to show $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$.
We have $(\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{B})\,\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ iff $\sum x_j \mathbf{b}_j = - \mathbf{x}$. Ideally I now want to use some property of solutions to Lyapunov equations, but I'm not sure where to go from here.
